# Is Google Earth Engine a data cube?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I recently discovered the word "datacube" and according to [wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_cube):

> In computer programming contexts, a data cube (or datacube) is a multi-dimensional ("n-D") array of values. Typically, the term datacube is applied in contexts where these arrays are massively larger than the hosting computer's main memory; examples include multi-terabyte/petabyte data warehouses and time series of image data.

The question is thus simple is Google Earth Engine a datacube ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this article can help:

> Gorelick, Noel, et al. "Google Earth Engine: Planetary-scale
> geospatial analysis for everyone." Remote sensing of Environment 202
> (2017): 18-27.
>
> https://doi.org/10.1016/j.rse.2017.06.031

It says:

> Images ingested into Earth Engine are pre-processed to facilitate fast
> and efficient access. First, images are cut into tiles in the image's
> original projection and resolution and stored in an efficient and
> replicated tile database. A tile size of 256 × 256 was chosen as a
> practical trade-off between loading unneeded data vs. the overhead of
> issuing additional reads. In contrast to conventional “data cube”
> systems, this data ingestion process is information-preserving: the
> data are always maintained in their original projection, resolution
> and bit depth, avoiding the data degradation that would be inherent in
> resampling all data to a fixed grid that may or may not be appropriate
> for any particular application.

Answer (score 0):

I think of a data cube as a 3 dimensional array. This includes 2 spatial dimensions (lat and long for example), one temporal dimension (the time-frame you are interested in), and any number of attributes (tree cover for example)--also a spatial reference system.

Comment: So yes, GEE is a data cube...

Comment: As the other answer says, GEE stores data independently. A data cube is a 3-dimensional array, GGE stores data as 2-dimensional arrays inside an image collection. Then you can build a data cube with functions, but GEE's data nature isn't a data cube